# What is the probability a confidence interval will contain the sample mean from future samples?

Tags: confidence-interval, error-propagation, delta-method

Suppose I observe $X_1, ..., X_n$ independent and identically distributed random variables and I calculate a confidence interval $(L, U)$ from this data. Now I take a second sample $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ from the same distribution. What is $P(L < \bar Y < U)$? How does it vary with $n$?

My initial thought was to use the delta method on $(\bar X, S^2)$, with

\begin{align}
g \begin{pmatrix}
    \bar X \\
    S^2
  \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
    \displaystyle \bar X - t_{1 - \alpha /2, n - 1} {S \over \sqrt n} \\
    \bar X \\
    \displaystyle \bar X + t_{1 - \alpha /2, n - 1} {S \over \sqrt n}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

But $\bar X$ and ${S \over \sqrt n}$ converge at different rates and I'm unsure how to handle this.

Finally, here's a quick simulation showing that for 10 samples from a standard normal, $P(L < \bar Y < U)$ is about 0.85:

```r
n <- 10

coverage <- function() {
  x <- rnorm(n)
  ci <- t.test(x)$conf.int
  once <- function() dplyr::between(mean(rnorm(n)), ci[1], ci[2])
  mean(purrr::map_dbl(1:500, ~once()))
}

mean(purrr::map_dbl(1:500, ~coverage()))
#> [1] 0.846428
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: In general, this question might not even make any sense.  For instance, when you construct a confidence interval for the variance of a distribution, you cannot validly compare values of the data to the variance--they are expressed in completely different units.  You are attempting to use a confidence interval as if it were a *prediction interval.*  This raises a question: what do you really need to accomplish? Do you need a procedure to construct a prediction interval or are you trying to learn something about interpreting confidence intervals (or neither)?

Comment: If you had a new sample, you could compute the new sample variance and compare it to an initial confidence interval for variance? I hadn't thought about prediction intervals because I was thinking about estimators rather than new data. Realizing a meta-analysis book is maybe the place to learn what a meaningful question is in this context.

Comment: There's no general answer to this. E.g. consider the absurd CI of 95% of the time the whole parameter space and 5% of the time the empty set. After seeing the CI you know whether the answer to your question is 100% or 0%. With other CIs this is not so clear, but similar effects may occur.